# Using Jury Conditions to Show Instability

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory, biology, nonlinear-dynamics, mathematical-biology

If I want to force an equilibrium point of a discrete dynamical system to be unstable can I just violate one of the conditions for stability stated in the jury conditions

$$|\mbox{Trace} (J)| < 1 + \det (J) < 2$$

For example, if I can force that |TraceJ| >=2 , have I shown instability for the equilibrium point in question?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please consider moving the mathematical question to the top and the motivation to the bottom.

Comment: Alright, Rodrigo, I will do that.

Comment: Yes, in your case, you will be unstable if the trace is larger than 2. Note that this only works for 2x2 matrices, which you have not mentioned. Alternatively, you can just check the location of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you KBS, I am indeed studying a 2x2 system.  I am a biologist not a mathematician, but I am a bit better at math than anyone in my research group so I get stuck doing all the coding and analysis.  Thanks so much my man!

Comment: @kmw1985 Please pay attention to the fact that if the eigenvalues are in the closed unit disc, then the approach is inconclusive and one has to go farther with the analysis.

Comment: Hello again KBS, I do not quite understand your second comment.  If I show that the traceJ > = 2, then I have shown that the eigenvalues must be outside of the unit disk, correct?

Comment: @KBS hi there, could you clarify what you mean about the eigenvalues being in the unit disk.  If I force the trace to be greater than two for one of the parameters in the trace then I hate shown instability and the eigenvalues cannot be in the unit disk, correct?

Comment: You need to make sure that at least one of the eigenvalues lies outside the closed unit disc. This means that the Jury stability criterion needs to be strictly violated.

Comment: @KBS not sure I am quite following.  So you are telling me that |TraceJ| >=2 is not enough to show the Jury Condition fails?  I need to show something like detJ >1 then?  Trying to avoid this since the detJ is insane.   Hrm.  Really trying to follow.

Comment: The Jury criterion says that if the conditions are satisfied, then all the eigenvalues lie within the unit disc. If they do not, then at least one eigenvalue lies on the unit circle or outside the closed unit disc. You need to make sure that at least one of the eigenvalues lie outside the closed unit disc. Then, for sure you will have instability of the fixed point.

Comment: What is $J$? The Jacobian of the state-transition function? I have never heard of "jury conditions". Please provide references.